# Magento 1.9 REST API failing with nonce_used error

Tags: magento, oauth

I have a Magento 1.9 CE install which I am trying to access via the REST API.
I keep getting the 'oauth_problem=nonce_used' error when I start the process by calling the oauth/initiate URL.

I have added some logging into the /Mage/Oauth/Model/Server.php _validateNonce method and despite what nonce I supply in the Postman request, the same nonce gets logged out. In other words, the nonce in the request disappears somehow and a previous nonce is retrieved from somewhere.

And it isn't just the nonce from the previous request. I called the oauth/initiate URL several times and the logged nonce was the same for all of them (and never the nonce passed in the request).

I'm not sure if this is a Magento thing or Apache/mod_rewrite is doing something as well.

Any thoughts much appreciated.

Comment: You can try with API cache disabled because some time it will take previous token.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The cache has been fully disabled for a while now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an issue with Postman rather than Magento. It wasn't updating the post data correctly.